# Does chrome cap requestframetime

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frame-rate

Made some animations in javascript. I made it in a 60 fps monitor so I didn't notice it till I tested it on my laptop which is 144 fps. The whole thing just doubled in speed.

I changed my screen refresh rate to 60 fps, the same machine then it went back to normal.

Just asking if this is a bug with chrome or, is chrome requestanimationframe really dependent on screen refresh rate.

Not really a problem, I just found it weird, I mean yeah I can just time the update, but yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in mozilla's developer doc:

> The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will
>   generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per
>   W3C recommendation.

So behavior is compliant to the description.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame